# Unable to get a new AWS token in my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

im using AWS authentication in my app, every time the app wakes up from the background, the following api is been called.

```
   AWSMobileClient.default().getTokens({ (tokens, error) in
     if let tokenString = tokens?.idToken?.tokenString {
       AppState.UserAuth.authToken = tokenString
      }
```

what is happening, after tracking the issue, is that when the session is expired, and this api is called, it doesn't return anything, tracked the library from inside, its just returning, with no completion handler.
Is there a way to refresh/check the token if its expired?